# PHP converting booleans sent via AJAX to strings

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm sending something like this to PHP using AJAX:

```
var details = [{name: "thing1", value: true}, {name: "thing2", value: true}, {name: "thing3", value: false}]

$.ajax({
    url: 'myphp.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {
        universalDetails: details,
    },
//...etc.
```

In my PHP, if I include this:

```
$universalDetails = $_POST["universalDetails"];
var_dump($universalDetails);
```

All of my `value`s are shown as strings in an array...like this:

`{ ["name"]=> string(20) "thing1" ["value"]=> string(4) "true" }`

What's happening here? How do I preserve these as booleans?

Answer (score 1):

That's by design, because each POST/GET Parameter is basically a string. You could try to do `if($_POST['universalDetails']['value'] == 'true') ...` because PHP will change a string `"true"` to a boolean with the value of `true`(not a string!):

More information: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting

But notice: `var_dump((bool) "false");   // bool(true)`